# Is calculating the index in an array more efficient than letting the compiler do it?

Tags: r, performance, indexing

I'm trying to generalize a neural network function to arbitrarily many layers, and so I need multiple matrices to hold the weights for each neuron in each layer. I was originally explicitly declaring matrix objects in R to hold my weights for each layer. Instead of having one matrix per layer, I thought of a way (not saying it's original), to store all of my weights in a single array and defined an "indexing function" to map a weight to its appropriate index in the array.

I defined the function as follows:

[image]

where [image] is the *k*-th weight of the *j*-th neuron in the *i*-th layer and *L(r)* is the number of neurons in layer *r*. After writing these definitions, I realize that stackoverflow doesn't allow latex like mathoverflow which is unfortunate. 
Now the question is: Is it more efficient to compute the index of my weights in this way, or is actually less efficient? 
After looking up how indices are computed for arrays in general, this is essentially what is done on compilation anyway if I just kept a matrix in each layer holding the weights, so it seems like I may just be making my code overly complicated and harder to understand if there's no difference in time efficiency.

Comment: I'm curious as to how you actually defined the indexing function in R code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** use the matrices its easier to understand and takes advantage of optimized CPU instructions.

---

In computer science parlance, the efficiency (scalability) of algorithms is reasoned about using [Big O cost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). A score can be given to both the time and space complexity.
Using Big O notation lets compare the two approaches:

### Array Approach

**time complexity**:
Array index access is `O(1)` time, no matter how large an array becomes, it is just as computationally easy to access an element given its index.

As you've created a function to compute the index of the `k-th` weight, this adds some small complexity but would probably run in constant `O(1)` time as it is a mathematical expression, so negligible.

**space complexity**:
`O(N)` where `N` is the number of weights across all layers.

### Matrices Approach

**time complexity**:
A matrix is essentially a 2d array with `O(1)` access

**space complexity**
`O(N + M)`, where `N` is number of neurons and `M` is number of weights.

---

Conceptually, we can see that the two approaches have an equivalent time and space complexity score.
However there are the other trade-offs involved (and as a good SO-er must inform you of those)

When it comes to working with the data in the array vs matrices approach, the array approach is less efficient as it circumvents the opportunity for [MISD operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISD). As @liborm alluded to there are vectorised (MISD) operations handled by lower level system libraries like `LAPACK/BLAS`, which "batch" CPU instructions for some matrix operations (less overhead cost to transfer and compute data at CPU compared to sending a new instruction every time)

> Instead of having one matrix per layer, I thought of a way ... to store all of my weights in a single array

It's hard to see why you would opt-ed for the latter as it requires you to create a bespoke indexing function. Maybe its nicer to think about all your weights being in one long array place? However I would argue the mental load required to maintain the array mapping is higher than having multiple matrices dedicated to a layer.

A hash-table like structure of matrices would be much easier to reason about

```
layers <- list(layer1 = [[...]], layer2 = [[...]], layerN = [[...]])
```

### Further reading

http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/4/16/vectorization-in-r--why.html

Comment: (+1) It's also worth noting that the time it takes to actually compute the vector index from the 3 coordinates with any R-defined function will be orders of magnitude higher than just indexing a list of matrices with those same coordinates.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thank you for the link on how R is run, that is very helpful. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There are many factors to take into consideration in each of the approaches. I'm not familiar with R but I'm assuming matrices' buffers are represented as one-dimensional arrays in memory. (Even if they are written as two dimensional arrays in the underlying C implementation the compiler stores it as one-dimensional array in memory)

The overall outline of memory operations are:

1. Case: Several matrices per layers

   - Allocation of matrices: [image: allocationmatrix]
   - Accessing of indices: [image: accesingindices]
2. Case: One matrix for all layers + index calculation

   - Allocation of matrix cost:  [image: onematrixallocation]
   - Accesing each of the indices cost: [image: accesingindicies]
   - Function cost: [image: functioncost]

We can clearly see that the second case, scales better, even though there's the additional cost of the function call.

Having said that, in general having a statically allocated array with all the weights for all the layers, should be faster.

In most cases, computers's bottleneck is memory bandwidth, and the best way to counteract this is to minimize the number of memory accesses.

With this in mind there's another more primitive reason why the 2nd approach will probably be faster: Caches.

Here's a good [explanation of the performance difference in accesing a two-dimensional array in a loop by Good Ol' Bob Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9936656/1412926)

TL; DR: Caches take advantage of the [principle of locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference), and therefore, having memory accesses spatially close to each other (as you would in one single array and accessing them in a cache-friendly way as explained in [Bob Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9936656/1412926)) renders better performance than having them spatially separated (having them in several distinct arrays).

PS: I also recommend to benchmark both approaches and compare, since these nuances regarding the cache are machine-dependent. It might be the case that the Dataset/NN is small enough to fit completely in RAM or even in cache? in a very powerful server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you want to use some kind of native array objects, so you get the speedups provided by BLAS/LAPACK implementations (see eg Intel MKL discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090206/linking-intels-math-kernel-library-mkl-to-r-on-windows?rq=1) if you're on Windows). Most of the time in NN evaluation will be spent in matrix multiplications (like SGEMM), and this is where BLAS implementations like Intel MKL can be an order of magnitude faster.

That is - even if the hand-coded indices for your single-array multi-layer network were super fast, you won't be able to use it with the optimised multiplication routines, which would make your whole network significantly slower. Use the native array objects and create a multi layer abstraction on top of them.

But actually if you want speed and usability (and to really build some NN models), you should consider using something like [R interface to TensorFlow](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com). As a bonus you'll get things like running on the GPU for free.

Comment: While this is nice information, this doesn’t answer the question at hand.

Comment: The answer is trying to direct you to the fact that computing indices for the array is one of the less important problems in NN evaluation speed - while keeping your data in one matrix per layer allows you to use the super fast code where it matters most. Will stress this a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Nice puzzle.. If you are asking calculating index in which would happen in runtime for which it needs to be compiled. Just want to understand how would you let the compiler compute it? IF you have a need to playing with the info anytime later then I would suggest to use Hasmap kind of mechanism. I had done it for a similar need.

Comment: By letting the compiler do it, I mean letting the weights be stored in a matrix in each in layer rather than being stored in a single array. I believe this technically is a hash map.