# Error: "cannot add binding of '.First' to the base environment"

Tags: r

I was using R and Rstudio with no specific problem. However, since today every time I open R, the following message appears:

> Error: cannot add binding of '.First' to the base environment.

Therefore, the same problem arise when I try to use RStudio. I haven't made any change to my computer or its system and its seems the problem appears suddently.

I used Windows 10 all updated installed, R version 4.1.0.

I have reinstalled R, updates every programs but the problem remains.

Any idea of what is going on ?

Comment: So you have an `.Rprofile` file in your home directory? Or `.Renviron`? The `?Startup` help page lists the places that files that have R code may be automatically run. Perhaps you have some bad code in there. Since they are not in the standard R application folders, they would not be removed or replaces with a reinstall.

Answer (score 10):

According to the [R-devel message board](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2021-May/080761.html), this is solved by using `assign()` in the `.Rprofile`. Previously one could assign these as objects directly,

```
.First <- function() cat("\n   Welcome to R!\n\n")
.Last <- function()  cat("\n   Goodbye!\n\n")
```

but [R 4.1.0](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html) has the following breaking change:

> The base environment and its namespace are now locked (so one can no longer add bindings to these or remove from these).

The following method should now be used:

```
assign(".First", function() cat("\n   Welcome to R!\n\n"), envir = globalenv())
assign(".Last", function() cat("\n   Goodbye!\n\n"), envir = globalenv())
```

Comment: The problem comes from the update of the package installR. I have stopped using it because of this "incompatibility" and update now the packages with RStudio.

Comment: Good to know that got it working for you! I'm on a team that has a shiny app in production that uses `Rprofile.site` and `Renviron.site` to point to R objects/database credentials upon initialization and also came upon this error during our most recent security patches. There appears to be little documentation on this issue. Hoping other folks who stumble upon this question might find it helpful

Comment: To clarify, you do not *need* to use `assign` (though there’s nothing wrong with it!), you just need to ensure that the object is assigned into the *correct environment*. `assign` is one way; another way is e.g. `.GlobalEnv$.First = function () …`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to make it work by re desinstalling everything and re re install R and Rstudio. I suspect the problem came from a package update.