# How to fix Error: cannot add binding of '.First' to the base environment

Tags: r

I get this message when I use R version 4.1.0:

> Error: "cannot add binding of '.First' to the base environment"

I followed the suggested method on your site:

`assign(".First", function() cat("\n   Welcome to R!\n\n"), envir = globalenv())`

`assign(".Last", function() cat("\n   Goodbye!\n\n"), envir = globalenv())`

but the problem was not solved.
I would appreciate any suggestion on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please clarify. You have edited your Rprofile.site file with this?

Comment: @Roland I am having the exact same problem and I have put this code in my Rprofile.site

Comment: @baibo can you provide the exact code you've added to Rprofile.site? also, are you sure you've added it to the *correct* Rprofile.site? (i.e., in the R subdirectory for the R version you're using?)

Comment: The reason is probably that from R 4.1 on : "The base environment and its namespace are now locked (so one can no longer add bindings to these or remove from these). ", see : https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html

Comment: The info about the locked base environment seems to be the explanation for the error message, but that still raises the question how `globalenv()` manages to return the base environment? At least I failed trying to replicate this on purpose.... Maybe the output of `print(globalenv())` and `print(rlang::env_parents(globalenv()))` (in RProfile.site) might help troubleshooting...

Comment: ok, reading the linked r-devel docs by @Waldi this may be very specific to R4.1.0, and was fixed in 4.1.1 `.First and .Last can again be set from the site profile.`   So updating R to at least 4.1.1 may solve the issue (I tried this on 4.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

I see you solved it by updating the version. But for version 4.1.0 checkout the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68198277/error-cannot-add-binding-of-first-to-the-base-environment) post. It might help.

Comment: Thanks: I knew of that question, but reinstalling R is not something I can do (I have a fixed version only)