# Error: cannot add binding of 'main.dir' to the base environment

Tags: r

After upgrading to R 4.1.2 I got the following error

Fejl: cannot add binding of 'main.dir' to the base environment

This is related to my Rprofile.site and related to these lines

```
main.dir <- 'E:/Users/jdoe/R'
setwd(main.dir)
```

It has always worked with earlier versions.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Does this help answer your question? [Error: "cannot add binding of '.First' to the base environment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68198277/error-cannot-add-binding-of-first-to-the-base-environment) The base environment is now closed.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. Gives the errormessage: Fejl i .globalEnv$main.dir <- "E:/Users/jdoe/R" : 
  cannot do complex assignments in base namespace
[Workspace loaded from E:/Users/jkanters/Dropbox (Panum Bros)/R/H index/.RData]

Comment: Thanks for Your reply but it still gives the error