# Build R with OpenBLAS

Tags: r, build, amd-processor, openblas, r-devel

I'm trying to build R-devel / R-patched. I've read some links, connected with steps for doing this.

```
1) https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/01/building-r-4-2-for-windows-with-openblas/
2) https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/05/building-r-4-for-windows-with-openblas/
3) https://github.com/r-windows/r-base
```

But unfortunatelly, without any success.

In "1" I have no "Makefile.win" and no file with "-lf77blas -latlas"
In "2" manually created "full-build.sh" script do not do anything.
In "3" I have an error with `Use_ATLAS=YES`

```
installing 'sysdata.rda'
make[3]: *** [../../../share/make/basepkg.mk:151: sysdata] Error 127
make[2]: *** [Makefile.win:22: all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile.win:32: R] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:18: all] Error 2
```

This error is connected with this row in basepkg.mk:

```
@$(ECHO) "tools:::sysdata2LazyLoadDB(\"$(srcdir)/R/sysdata.rda\",\"$(top_builddir)/library/$(pkg)/R\")" | \
  R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES=NULL LC_ALL=C $(R_EXE)
```

So, could anyone helps me, pls? What's wrong with these 3 ways? How it's possible to build R devel correctly (with installation file if possible)? Also is it possible to compile this with AMD BLIS library (I have Ryzen 9 5950x).

Thank you.

P.S. I use Windows 11 and gcc-12.02 from winlibs
P.P.S. If possible, please, add a recipe for building R with AMD BLIS...

Comment: There is no one-size-fits-all answer to this question, as the process of building R from source will vary depending on your specific system and configuration. However, some general tips that may be helpful include:

-Ensure that you have the required dependencies installed on your system before beginning the build process.
-If you are using the ATLAS library, make sure that you have the correct version installed for your system architecture (i.e. 32-bit or 64-bit).
-If you encounter errors during the build process, try searching for solutions online or on the R-devel mailing list.

Comment: @LuckyOwl I have OpenBLAS compiled and built on my current machine with gcc. So, all links for libs, connected with ATLAS/OPENBLAS were put in the MkRules.local

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
1) https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/howto-R-devel.html # the canonical guide for compiling R-devel on Windows using Rtools
2) https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/01/building-r-4-2-for-windows-with-openblas/ # adapt parts of this guide to get openblas with R
```

Following the 2 above links, here are some basic steps:

## 1. Install Rtools43

(i) [Download](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools43/files/rtools43-5493-5475.exe); (ii) Install it to default location (i.e., `C:\rtools43`)

## 2. Install MikTeX and Inno Setup

> MikTeX (with basic packages and inconsolata) is needed to build package vignettes and documentation. Inno Setup is needed to build the R installer.

## 3. General setup

1. Run the Msys2 shell (`c:/rtools43/msys2.exe`)
2. Make a folder to store the source files: `mkdir /c/R-devel`
3. Update Msys2: `pacman -Syuu` it may update only the core stuff first, then ask you to close the terminal. You should follow the instructions, then relaunch Msys2 shell and rerun `pacman -Syuu` a second time to fully update all the components
4. Install wget and subversion: `pacman -Sy wget subversion`
5. Change the working directory to the folder created in step 3.2: `cd /c/R-devel`
6. Grab latest Tcl/Tk bundle from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools43/files/), a file named such as `tcltk-5493-5412.zip`:

   ```
    TCLBUNDLE=tcltk-5493-5412.zip
    wget https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools43/files/$TCLBUNDLE
   ```
7. Grab the latest R version (R-devel), and unzip Tcl:

   ```
    svn checkout https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk
    cd trunk
    unzip ../$TCLBUNDLE
   ```

## 4. Add a `MkRules.local` in `/c/R-devel/trunk/src/gnuwin32/`

You can use Notepad++ to create a new `MkRules.local` file with the following contents (**edit `ISDIR = ...` to the appropriate directory in step 2**):

```
USE_ATLAS = YES
EOPTS = -march=native -pipe
QPDF = /usr
ISDIR = C:/Program Files (x86)/Inno Setup 6
```

## 5. Adjust `/c/R-devel/trunk/src/extra/blas/Makefile.win`

You can use Notepad++ to change the line `-L../../../$(IMPDIR) -lR  -L"$(ATLAS_PATH)" -lf77blas -latlas` to `-L../../../$(IMPDIR) -lR -fopenmp -lopenblas`

```
-          -L../../../$(IMPDIR) -lR  -L"$(ATLAS_PATH)" -lf77blas -latlas
+          -L../../../$(IMPDIR) -lR -fopenmp -lopenblas
```

## 6. Compile R

1. Run the Msys2 shell and change to appropriate working directory: `cd /c/R-devel/trunk/src/gnuwin32/`
2. Set environment variables as follows (**update the MiKTeX installation directory in the commands below**):

   ```
    export PATH=/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/bin:$PATH
    export PATH=/c/Users/xxxxxxxx/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/:$PATH
    export TAR="/usr/bin/tar"
    export TAR_OPTIONS="--force-local"
   ```
3. Test that the tools are available: `which make gcc pdflatex tar`
4. Build R installer:

   ```
    make rsync-recommended
    make distribution
   ```
5. The installer will be available at: `/c/R-devel/trunk/src/gnuwin32/installer/R-devel-win.exe`

## 7. Test if our R compilation utilize OpenBLAS

[The following R code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42854705/9454926) should run much faster compare to standard R for Windows downloaded from CRAN:

```
m <- 10000
n <- 2000
A <- matrix (runif (m*n),m,n)
system.time (S <- svd (A,nu=0,nv=0))

user  system elapsed 
4.02    0.65    7.83
```

Comment: Sorry for my long time silence, but stil have the same error: i`nstalling 'sysdata.rda'
make[4]: *** [../../../share/make/basepkg.mk:151: sysdata] Error 127`

Comment: I implemented all steps described by you. With no effect, unfortunatelly.((( Possible, the problem is cinnected with my Windows / Rtools configuration, may it be?

Comment: 'installing 'sysdata.rda'
make[4]: *** [../../../share/make/basepkg.mk:151: sysdata] Error 127
make[3]: *** [Makefile.win:22: all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [Makefile.win:32: R] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:18: all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:399: distribution] Error 2
'

Comment: @Dmitriy every time you need to run the Msys2 shell (`c:/rtools43/msys2.exe`), can you try it with "Run as administrator" (Right click the `msys2.exe` and pick that option)?

Comment: yes, I did it. No effect, still have the same error.