# Building problem of R-devel in Windows 11 and binutils

Tags: r, msys2, rtools

I'm trying to compile R devel by this advice:

[Build R with OpenBLAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74086774/build-r-with-openblas)

I use MSYS2 (Rtools 4.3), but now have strange error:

```
-------- Building ../../../bin/x64/Rblas.dll --------
gcc  -s -shared  -o ../../../bin/x64/Rblas.dll blas00.o ../../gnuwin32/dllversion.o Rblas.def \
   -L../../../bin/x64 -lR  -L""/c/Repository/AMD/WinLibs"" -fopenmp -lamdblas
C:\rtools43\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: internal error: aborting at ../../binutils-2.40/ld/ldlang.c:527 in compare_section
C:\rtools43\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: please report this bug
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [Makefile.win:14: ../../../bin/x64/Rblas.dll] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:236: Rblas] Error 2
make[2]: *** [Makefile:115: rbuild] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:17: all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:399: distribution] Error 2
```

I did just only one change in `Makefile.win` as described at link above:

```
-   -L../../../$(IMPDIR) -lR  -L"$(ATLAS_PATH)" -lf77blas -latlas
+   -L../../../$(IMPDIR) -lR  -L"$(ATLAS_PATH)" -fopenmp -lamdblas
```

(with `-lamdblas -lamdlapack` instead of `-lamdblas` the problem is still existing). `libamdblas, libamdlapack` are just renamed versions of `amd-blis` and `amd-libfire` libraries from `AOCL`.

I found the same problem described earlier:

https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/15469

But I see that It can be fixed only with downgrading `binutils` to 2.39 or upgrade to 2.40-2.
Unfortunately, I haven't found ways to do this on `MSYS2` under Windows.

Could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the `ld` issue is explained in [Bug 30079 - Mingw ld : linking against an import lib causes `ld` to `abort()` at `compare_section` in `ldlang.c`](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30079#c3)

But the crux of your question is: "how to downgrade/upgrade binutils in Msys2?".

That would be done with [MSys2 package management](https://www.msys2.org/docs/package-management/)

To downgrade binutils to version 2.39 or upgrade to version 2.40-2 with MSYS2 on Windows 11, you will need to use the `pacman` package manager.

Find the specific version of the `binutils` package that you want to install.

```bash
pacman -Ss binutils
```

This command will display a list of available `binutils` packages.

Then install it (with its dependencies) using:

```bash
pacman -S <name of the package>
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer fully correct, but unfortunatelly, the problem is deeper than installed binutils via pacman - I installed 2.39-2, but got the same problem with make distribution. I think It's connected with an installation package of RTools+R.

Comment: @Dmitriy OK. Maybe some PATH conflict then?

Comment: I'll try to investigate. It's not so easy, because I still have no idea how to check structure of `rtools43-toolchain-libs-full-5550.tar.zst` (I suppose that binutils files are located at this "location".