Change the BLAS version used by R
I am currently having issues with the 'Eigen()' function in R.
It was mentioned that I should try using 'OpenBLAS'. How abouts should I go about installing this and make R use this version of BLAS.
I am on an Ubuntu 22.04 machine.
I have also heard about MLK, how would I go about using this?

Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74086774/build-r-with-openblas?

Take a look at flexiblas, no need to recompile R.

@jay.sf thanks for this, I need to see if this works for an Ubuntu machine. The webpage only seems to mention fedora.

@DylanDijk They describe how to do it on Ubuntu there: https://www.mpi-magdeburg.mpg.de/2427308/flexiblas_install
